# Vue 2.7 unit testing of composition api fails with defineProps is undefined

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, ts-jest, vue-test-utils

I'm trying out vue 2.7 and the composition API to get a feel on how it's like to work with and due to it's better TS type inference.

Building the app works flawlessly now and linting and typechecks are all ok.

My issue is that when I try to run my jest unit test the component mounting fails due to
defineProps being undefined. I have no idea why that would be the case.

This is being run in a large rush monorepo where vue 2.7 is an allowed version, do not know if that is relevant.

> ReferenceError: defineProps is not defined

```
  49 | }
  50 |
> 51 | const props = defineProps<Props>();
     | ^
  52 | const { selectedAgreement, agreements, scopeId } = props;
  53 |
  54 | const t = translateMixin.methods.t;

  at Object.<anonymous> (components/oe-dirigent-top-row.vue:51:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (b2b-oe-dirigent.vue:7:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (b2b-oe-dirigent.spec.ts:1:1)
  at TestScheduler.scheduleTests (../../../common/temp/node_modules/.pnpm/@jest+core@27.5.1/node_modules/@jest/core/build/TestScheduler.js:333:13)
  at runJest (../../../common/temp/node_modules/.pnpm/@jest+core@27.5.1/node_modules/@jest/core/build/runJest.js:404:19)
  at _run10000 (../../../common/temp/node_modules/.pnpm/@jest+core@27.5.1/node_modules/@jest/core/build/cli/index.js:320:7)
  at runCLI (../../../common/temp/node_modules/.pnpm/@jest+core@27.5.1/node_modules/@jest/core/build/cli/index.js:173:3)
```

Running vue/test-utils@1.1.3 and @vue/vue-jest@27.0.0-alpha.4